# No collation was set by the server for the current connection in TediousJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, tedious

I'm using the [newBulkLoad](https://tediousjs.github.io/tedious/api-connection.html#function_newBulkLoad) method of the Connection class of TediousJS.

After trying to execute this piece of code:

```
bulkLoad.addRow(TYPES.Null, col2, col3, col4, col5, TYPES.Null, col7, 
                                col8, col9, TYPES.Null, TYPES.Null, TYPES.Null);
```

I'm receiving the following error on that line:

> No collation was set by the server for the current connection

I've previously setup the columns as specified in the URL above. What does this error mean? How can I solve it?